# add items in layout border - extjs

Tags: layout, extjs, border, extjs4, items

i need to add two boxes in the north section of a [layout border](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.layout.container.Border)

it would be something like this : in red the boxes / panels i need to add (but i dont want to keep borders)
[image]

here is my try :

```
...
{

        region: 'north', 
        split: true,
       //xtype : 'box',
        height: 100,
        layout : 'anchor',

        items: [{ xtype: 'box', id: 'header', height: 100, anchor: '70%',
                  html: '<h1> my title</h1>'},
                {
                    xtype: 'panel', title: 'title', border: 'false', frame: false,  height: 100,
                    html: '<h1> my info</h1>'
                }]
    }
...
```

the second panel doesnt work

thanks for ur help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better using a border layout again in the north region...

```
region: 'north', 
split: true,
//xtype : 'box',
height: 100,
layout : 'border',
items: [{ 
      xtype: 'box',
      id: 'header',
      region: 'center',
      height: 100,
      anchor: '70%',
      html: ' my title'
}, { 
      xtype: 'panel',
      region: 'east'
      border: 'false',
      frame: false,
      height: 100,
      width: '49%',
      html: ' my info'
   }]
...
```

That should work okay.

Comment: it worked, i have tried before i must have missed something,thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want further partition of your north panel, then you should use **layout:'border'**.
Otherwise you can add your items to the north region derectly without using layout.
If you don't want the border,You should use **border:false**

Comment: would u take a look at my [current issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453312/show-different-item-on-selectionchange-on-a-grid) ,thanks